# How to send something to the server?

Tags: c

I was given this code and my task is to send something to the server using the console and read it in it.

Maybe someone knows how to do it for me or maybe give me a hint where to start.

Because we were given the source  code but how to work with it and what to do next, we were not told anything

Maybe someone already has experience in this and can help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    iResult = getaddrinfo("147.175.115.34", "777", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else
        printf("getaddrinfo did not fail...\n");


    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    ptr = result;

    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else
        printf("Any error occured...\n");


    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int) ptr->ai_addrlen);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("Not connected to server...\n");
    else
        printf("Connected to server!\n");

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    Sleep(250);

    char sendbuf[4096];

    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 4096

    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];


    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: It seems you are only missing the part to read from console? Just read something into `sendbuf` with `fgets` for example.

Comment: Who gave you this code?  Print out the TCP RFC, roll it up and hit them about the head:)

Answer (score 1):

well you need to put something in 'sendbuf' before the send call.

like say

```
   strcpy(sndbuf, "Hello Server");
```

BTW the receive code is totally wrong. You must loop on the receive until you have received all the data

Comment: @kaylum nope - except for wrong spelling of sendbuff - corrected - ty for the catch